# Hadoop HA Namenode goes down with the Error: flush failed for required journal (JournalAndStream(mgr=QJM to [< ip >:8485, < ip >:8485, < ip >:8485]))

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, high-availability, bigdata

Hadoop Namenode goes down almost everyday once.

```
FATAL namenode.FSEditLog (JournalSet.java:mapJournalsAndReportErrors(398)) - 

**Error: flush failed for required journal** (JournalAndStream(mgr=QJM to [< ip >:8485, < ip >:8485, < ip >:8485], stream=QuorumOutputStream starting at txid <>))
java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting 20000ms for a quorum of nodes to respond.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.AsyncLoggerSet.waitForWriteQuorum(AsyncLoggerSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumOutputStream.flushAndSync(QuorumOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogOutputStream.flush(EditLogOutputStream.java:113)
    at
```

Can someone suggest what are the things that I need to look into for resolving this issue?

I am using VMs for the journal nodes and master nodes. Does it cause any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this issue was caused due to the difference in the system time between the nodes of the cluster.

To keep the system time in sync, we can execute the commands below in each node.

```
sudo service ntpd stop

sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org  # Run this command multiple times

sudo service ntpd start
```

If hue is down, run below command on the hue server machine

```
sudo service hue start
```

If namenode is down, start the namenode.

## Recurring fix

Add a crontab for the root user on all the nodes of the environment.

or

Install VM tools, to keep the system time in sync.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you pasted. It appears your journal nodes could not talk to the NN in a timely manner. What was going on at the time of this event?

Since you mention that your nodes are vms I would guess you overloaded the hypervisor or it had troubling talking from the NN to the JN and zk quorum.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: @WillieCheng I am with you, but I recommend to improve the "appeal" of helpful comments like that with a different phrasing, making use of the convenient shortcuts `[tour]` and `[answer]`; e.g. ...

Comment: Hi Fixxar. Please take the highly recommend [tour], which among other things will introduce you to the best practices on [answer].

Comment: Though in this case, the author already did take the tour. Still the hints on answering stay applicable.